# Setting "charset" on the back end vs. the front end

Tags: php, html, http

I can set "charset" on the back end (PHP):

```
header('charset=utf-8');
```

I can also set it on the front end (HTML):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Where should I set it and why?

Comment: Setting the content type on server side should typically be enough - the Meta tag is usually used to override a server side setting that you can't change. (IIRC tag trumps headers in any scenario). I'll leave it to people with actual sources to provide answers though :)

Comment: FYI: to align your database charset (in case of MySQL), you could use : `mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");`

Comment: @Pekka웃 - You don't recall correctly. HTTP header beats HTML tag, BOM beats HTTP Header. User's browser selection beats BOM. Rules are [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding).

Comment: @Alohci thanks! I thought the header was used traditionally to enforce an encoding when you were unable to change it server side, but I may be misremembering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set it at the server level in your Apache or Nginx or whatever configuration.

The short answer is that it doesn't matter that much for most user-facing browser use cases. Most browsers will interpret both the back-end and front-end charset tags the same.

That being said, setting the tag on the back-end is preferable in many instances.  It slightly decreases the total amount of HTML that is sent to the user, it will show up in a HEAD http request, and such.  Additionally, some other meta tags, such as the X-UA-Compatible meta tag, behave strangely in some cases if set on the front-end.